# page is not processed if content is in a while loop

Tags: php

```
<?php 
include("global-settings.php"); 
session_start(); 
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error()); 
$email       = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email'])); 
$password  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(sha1($_POST['password']))); 

$result  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        $_SESSION['user_pid']    = $row['user_pid']; 
        $_SESSION['firstname']     = $row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION['lastname']     = $row['last_name']; 
        header("Location: ../protected/home.php"); 
    } else {
        $userid_generator = uniqid(rand(), false); 
        $date = date("Y/m/d"); 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_pid, username, password, datetime_registered) 
        VALUES('$userid_generator', '$email', '$password', '$date')")or die(mysql_error()); 
        $_SESSION['userid']    = $userid_generator; 
        $_SESSION['firstname']     = $row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION['lastname']     = $row['last_name']; 

        $leaders_query = "SELECT * FROM leaders"; 
        $leaders   = mysql_query($leaders_query); 

            $id = $row['id']; 
            mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO friends (node1id, node2id, is_leader, friends_since, friend_type) 
            VALUES('$id', '$userid_generator', 'Yes', '$date', 'full)")or die(mysql_error());     
    }
        }
?>
```

for some reason the while loop doesn't seem to work. It leaves a blank screen when I insert the content inside the while loop. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is a bit wonky. There's no need for a while loop in this case (using one for what should only ever produce at most a single row of data is evidence of cargo cult programming). The logic flow should be:

```
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION stuff
} else {
   ... create user record ...
}
```

As well, what is the point of the `SELECT * FROM Leaders` query? You don't actually fetch anything from that query so basically it's a useless operation.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is wrong: your if(mysql_num_rows(...)) should be before the while(mysql_fetch_array(...)) loop.
Try something like this:

```
<?php 
    include("global-settings.php"); 
    session_start(); 
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $email       = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email'])); 
    $password  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(sha1($_POST['password']))); 

    $result  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_pid']    = $row['user_pid']; 
        $_SESSION['firstname']     = $row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION['lastname']     = $row['last_name']; 
        header("Location: ../protected/home.php"); 
    } else {
        $userid_generator = uniqid(rand(), false); 
        $date = date("Y/m/d"); 
        $res_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_pid, username, password, datetime_registered) 
        VALUES('$userid_generator', '$email', '$password', '$date'); SELECT MAX(user_pid) FROM users;") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $_SESSION['userid']     = $userid_generator; 
        $_SESSION['firstname']  = $row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION['lastname']   = $row['last_name']; 

        $leaders_query = "SELECT * FROM leaders"; 
        $leaders   = mysql_query($leaders_query); 

        $id = mysql_insert_id($res_insert);
        mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO friends (node1id, node2id, is_leader, friends_since, friend_type) 
        VALUES('$id', '$userid_generator', 'Yes', '$date', 'full)") or die(mysql_error());     
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the resultset is empty, you can change de while for a do while, so it will be executed at least once.

the way it is, you are trying to count if there are rows inside the while, if there is none, it will never pass through there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include("global-settings.php");
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["email"]));
$password = sha1($_POST["password"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' AND password = '{$password}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or exit("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "<br>IN QUERY: " . $sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['user_pid'];
    echo "logged in";
} else {
    $userid_generator = uniqid(rand(), false);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_pid, email, password, datetime_registered, is_leader) VALUES ('$userid_generator', '{$email}', '{$password}', NOW(), 'no')");
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $leaders = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_leader LIKE '%yes%'");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($leaders)) {
            if ($rows['is_leader'] == 'yes') {
                $leader_id = $rows['user_pid'];
                mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO friends (node1id, node2id, friends_since, friend_type)
                VALUES('$leader_id', '$userid_generator', NOW(), 'full')");
                $_SESSION["userid"] = $userid_generator;
                echo "new user created and logged in";
                }

    if(is_dir($userid_generator)) {
    echo "Something wen't wrong. A bug report has been sent and we are doing what we can to fix it.";
    $message = 'Registration problem on account number $userid_generator. The user succesfully registered, but there is already
    a directory with the account id of $userid_generator.';
    mail($bug_report_email, "Registration Bug!", $message);
    } else {
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/photos', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/backups', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/videos', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/documents', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/developer', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/developer/apps', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/developer/themes', 0777);
    mkdir('../media/User-PID{' . $userid_generator . '}/xml', 0777);
}
}
}
?>
```

I actually fixed it. Thanks for your all's help though!